# JSF - Updating values on xhtml after Lazy DataGrid filled

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've an easy question.

I use `LazyDataModel` with dataGrid of primefaces in `ViewScoped` bean. And I have other `String` values 
 with their getters/setters methods.

My problem is I can't update my values on .xhtml page after my `LazyDataModel` is filled as it works late.

I set my string values in lazyDataModel's `@Override load` function.

Could you suggest me a way to update the values after lazyDataModel is filled?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Could you please post your DataModel and your .xhtml file ?

Comment: in load function, I update my string value depending on the search result count to show a message like "we found 'N' datasets" or "Sorry, no datasets found". And in .xhtml page I wanna show it in easy way: <h:outputText id="totalStr" value="#{myBean.myText}"/>